# Como hacer un submit a un jsp desde una ventana modal?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, jsp

Tengo el siguiente método en mi controller que recupera datos de una consulta que tengo en otros metodos

```
@RequestMapping(value= "/obtenerDatos")
public void obtener(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, Model model){

    Object attribute = (Object) request.getSession().getAttribute("listDatos");
    List<Factura> factura = (List<Factura>)attribute;

    Object attribute2 = (Object) request.getSession().getAttribute("listDatos1");
    List<Cliente> cliente = (List<Cliente>)attribute2;

    model.addAtribute("listDatos",factura.get(0).getValor());
    model.addAtribute("listDatos1",cliente.get(0).getValor());
}
```

Tengo en mi jsp1 un modal con un boton, el cual manda a llamar a la siguiente funcion:

```html
function obtenerDatos(){

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    content-type: "applicaction/json",
    url: "${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/obtenerDatos"
    error: function (e){
    console.log("ERROR", e);
    },
    done: function (e){
      console.log("DONE", e);
    }
  });
}


<button type="button" onclick="obtenerDatos()"></button>
```

Entonces  a la hora de dar click en el boton, entra a mi método de mi controller y en otro jsp2, recupero esos datos de la siguiente manera y realizo una operación

```html
<input type="hidden" id="valor1" name="valor1" value="${factura.get(0).getValor()}">

<input type="hidden" id="valor2" name="valor2" value="${cliente.get(0).getValor()}">

function sumar(){
  var num1 = parseInt($(#valor1).val());
   var num2 = parseInt($(#valor2).val());

   var total = num1 + num2;
  
  document.getElementById("inputTotal").value=total;
}
```

Tengo otro jsp que es el que contiene el menu  y es aquí donde llamo  al jsp1,

```html
$(document.ready(function(){         
   iniciaModal(); 
 })

function modal(){  
  $("#idModal"  ).modal("show");
}

< li id=" 1"><a  href="#" onclick =" modal()">MODAL</a></li>
  
Y aquí incluyo  el jsp1 
<%@include file="../jsp1.jsp" %>
```

Y en el jsp1

```html
function iniciaModal(){
}
 <div class="idModal" class="modal-fade">
   Aquí tengo el botón que menciono
</div>
```

y si me pinta el resultado de la suma en mi input, pero lo hace hasta que recargue la pagina,  o sea en el primer jsp tengo el modal con el boton que mencione, y al hacer click recupera los datos del controlador y los recupera en otro jsp para mostrar la operación, y lo que quiero que haga es que al dar click en el boton y al cerrar el modal, el resultado ya me aparezca, y que no tenga que andar recargando la pagina para ver el resultado

como le puedo hacer?
Como se implementa el ajax para que haga esta acción que quiero?, o como hago un submit al jsp2, con el boton que tengo en mi modal del jsp1?

Comment: No te acabo de seguir. Tienes una página principal, que sería jsp1 digamos, y un modal que tiene un botón que llama a un método del controller que devuelve unos datos resultado de un cálculo que haces. A ese método lo llamas mediante Ajax y cuando obtienes los datos no haces nada con ellos, simplemente un console.log. ¿Por qué no actualizas el input en ese momento en que recibes la respuesta del controlador? ¿Para qué necesitas el jsp2? ¿Desde dónde se está llamando a ese jsp2?

Comment: Mi jsp2 es el principal, ahí es donde tengo la función "sumar", ya que en ese jsp quiero pintar en el input el resultado de la operación, en el jsp1 está el modal con un formulario y el botón que mencioné, este modal se muestra sobre el jsp2 cunado doy click en un menú nav bar,  lo  que hace ahorita es que cuando yo doy click  en el botón del modal recuperó los datos y los jalo  en el jsp2, y si lo hace, pero tengo que cerrar el modal y recargar el jsp2 para visualizař el resultado, y lo que yo quiero es que al hacer click en el botón y al cerrar el modal ya muestre el resultado sin recargar

Comment: ¿Cómo abres el modal? Pon el código, por favor

Comment: Ya agregue lo que tengo,disculpa que no esté bien editado,  es que estoy desde el móvil,  gracias

Comment: Prueba a capturar el evento que se produce al cerrar el modal. Algo como $("#idModal"  ).on('close', function() { console.log('pasa'); });

Comment: Pero en que parte? Cuando doy click en mi botón?

Comment: Yo lo añadiría antes de abrir el modal. Para probar te vale, por ejemplo, antes de $("#idModal").modal("show");